# MediaPlayer - Playing and stopping when let go and press on button

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm gonna start by sharing the code that I have.

```
package com.example.onebuttonpressimage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;    // new import library for onclick listener


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // declare the objects and variables
    private ImageButton buttonJava;  // creates the JAVA object that holds button attributes and methods
    private MediaPlayer sound = null; // creates the JAVA object that holds the mediaplayer attributes and methods
    //private boolean pressed=false;

    // Creates the app window ===================================================================================
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);             // ties the JAVA mediaplayer object to the sound file
        buttonJava = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonXML);  // ties the JAVA button object to the XML object


        buttonJava.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    buttonJava.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                    sound.start();
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    buttonJava.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_not_pressed);
                }
             return false;
            }
        });



}}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make this play the sound until I let go of the button. I tried using `sound.stop()` but then it will only work once and then no longer work until I relaunch the app. Does anyone have any ideas? I want to try making it behave the way I need it without adding too much more to it. If anyone needs more clarification on what I need, please let me know. The following is my XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.onebuttonpressedimage.MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonXML"
        android:background="@drawable/blue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also insert how your xml looks like ?

Comment: I am adding it now

Comment: It is now added

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do it myself after some modifications to the buttonJava java code with some of the seekTo, Looping, and stopping when let go to make it work better.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick -

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // declare the objects and variables
    private ImageButton buttonJava;  // creates the JAVA object that holds button attributes and methods
    private MediaPlayer sound = null; // creates the JAVA object that holds the mediaplayer attributes and methods
    //private boolean pressed=false;

    // Creates the app window ===================================================================================
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);             // ties the JAVA mediaplayer object to the sound file
        sound.setLooping(true);
        buttonJava = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonXML);  // ties the JAVA button object to the XML object


        buttonJava.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    buttonJava.setPressed(true);
                    sound.start();

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    buttonJava.setPressed(false);
                    sound.pause();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also Use button selector instead of setting button background in onTouchListener as follow -

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mid.test.helpttest.MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:id="@+id/buttonXML"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**drawable/button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_pressed" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```